# Ensure a `std::vector` won't move its pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-management

In C++, a `std::vector<T>` is basically a pointer (`T*`), a size object (`int`) and a capacity object (`int`).

At construction, `std::vector` creates a new pointer `T*` and as the vector grows, `std::vector` is responsible for allocating the needed memory as the vector grows. If the vector grows so that there is no more room to add elements `T`, then `std::vector` will automatically move the pointer to another location and copy the data over.

Is it possible to tell the vector what pointer to use at construction and indicate a fix size and abort if program attempts to make the vector bigger than the size indicated at construction time?

Comment: You can provide your own allocator.

Comment: If you want something vector-like which has O(1) random-access but without ever relocating an element, take a look at `std::deque`. (But that is a more sophisticated datastructure than just a pointer and a couple of sizes.)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem - there's probably a better design pattern depending on why you want to do this. E.g. if the objects will be corrupted by moving then they should have better, or deleted, move-constructors etc.

Comment: I suspect you're calling `.data()` or `.front()` on the vector and caching the raw pointer somewhere. But then the vector grows and the pointer is invalid.  There's all kinds of ways to solve it, but you should elaborate on *what you are really trying to do...*.  Perhaps with a code sample.

Comment: I remembered that EASTL provides a fixed size vector (among other fixed size containers). You might look at that. https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/fixed_vector.h

Comment: @M.M and selbie Following your advice I opened [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842027/how-to-have-continuous-memory-in-a-simple-hierarchical-class-relationships). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `std::vector` doesn't provide a direct way of doing that.

`std::vector` allocates space via an allocator object though. If you wanted to, it would be fairly easy to write a minimal allocator that had an extra call to disable allocation and call abort if allocation were attempted after it was disabled.

Comment: Allocators also offer the convenient `max_size` function that could be exploited here.